# JSTL split keep blank or empty strings

Tags: split, jstl, retain

I am trying to use JSTL split on a string which has '|' as delimiter. However, if there is no value in between, the split is omitting this in the final array.

eg: abc|def||jkl

i want the array to contain (4 items)
'abc;
'def'
''
'jkl'

but, the split skips the empty value and i get only 3 items.

I know in js we can add the -1 parameter to avoid this issue. How do we solve this in JSTL?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jstl-1.1-mr2-spec-oth-JSpec/), `fn:split` internally uses `StringTokenizer` and therefor the behavior is the same as `StringTokenizer`.

So I think it is difficult to implemtent only by JSTL. One possible solution is to use `java.lang.String.split()`. For example, the following code:

```
<% request.setAttribute("strings", "abc|def||jkl".split("\\|")); %>
<c:forEach var="string" items="${strings}" varStatus="status">
<c:out value="${status.index}"/>:<c:out value="${string}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

prints out:

```
0:abc 1:def 2: 3:jkl
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. how can i achieve this if the string to be split is an array from JSTL.

I want to change this 

 <c:forEach var="items" items="${properties.labeldata}" varStatus="status">
<c:set var="listItem" value="${fn:split(items,'|')}" />

where items is the array. I can't do this, as the below is a scriptlet and items is not defined for it yet.

 <% request.setAttribute("listItem", items.split("\\|")); %>

Comment: never mind, i solved it like so

 <% String items = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("items");
    request.setAttribute("listItem", items.split("\\|",-1)); %>

Thanks for the help.

Comment: i still feel JSTL needs the -1 option like in java.

Comment: I think so, too :-)